# Calculation of drain current in JFET

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, jfet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA45MO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I<sub>DSS</sub>= 10mA and V<sub>p</sub>= -5V, when V<sub>DS</sub>=V<sub>p</sub>, what is the value of I<sub>D</sub> and V<sub>GS</sub>?

Lets say I apply KVL on drain-source loop.

Then I get VDD-I<sub>D</sub>R<sub>D</sub>-V<sub>DS</sub>=0.

Substitute the value then I get I<sub>D</sub>=2.1x10<sup>-3</sup>.
After that, I apply

[image]

Solve the formula and get V<sub>GS</sub>=2.71V

Is the method I used correctly in solving this question?

Comment: But in your schematics, Vgs voltage is equal to Vgg thus Vgs = -1V

Comment: You have to make a design choice of the required Vds to determine the Id. 5V would be a reasonable value giving 0.5mA.

Comment: You're in the "just applying formulas" mode without looking at the circuit to see what actually is happening. As G36 comments, there's a Vgs applied. What does that Vgs mean for the JFET?

Comment: But isn't that there is a potential drop across the R1 resistor? Wouldn't this make Vgg not equal to Vgs? Or the resistor does not have effect on the circuit?

Comment: the normal method is to use KVL in GS loop and then use the current formula. Now you have two-equation and two unknown and you may find ID and VGS.